# Programmatic check of R package version

Tags: r, r-markdown, devtools

I'm building an Rmarkdown document reliant on a frequently updated data package that's hosted on github.

How do I make sure that the document is always built using the latest version of the package, without installing the package on each build?

Comment: Read just the description file from Github and read the version number out of it? E.g., you could use `readLines` on [this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tidyverse/dplyr/master/DESCRIPTION)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the list of commits to a package by getting the `commits` page for the package.  For example,

```
https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/commits
```

shows that there were commits today.  If you save a copy of the top hash in that response (currently `af75177`), and then update whenever it changes, you should be sure to have the latest version.

However, this is likely a bad policy.  The package is not necessarily in a working condition after a commit:  perhaps the author is planning another one a minute later to finish some update.  It's much safer to use `update.packages()` and only get the updates that are judged to be stable enough to be sent to and accepted on CRAN.